# An alternative to using the word testee

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a different word to 'testee' to use for describing a person who submits samples to be tested, but isn't a patient. This applies to the situation like an athlete submitting samples for drug testing, or a person who is getting tests on allergy done. The reason I want to use a different word is to avoid confusion between using tester and testee.

Comment: 'Examinee' might work in the circumstances you describe.

Comment: I regularly use ***subject*** to describe a person undergoing a test.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities:

*sender*

*shipper*

*submitter*

*sample submitter*

But if the important thing is not the sending, but the creating of the sample to be submitted, then I support *subject* from @michael.hor257k, and I encourage him to submit an answer with this great word.

Comment: @PapaPoule - good idea.  It's funny -- "provider" by itself wouldn't work, because it suggests "medical provider", e.g. doctor or nurse practitioner.